# Number of points required for getting exact answer using Gauss quadrature for a non-polynomial function.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, quadrature

I have been trying to evaluate the following integral using Gauss Legendre quadrature.

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \int_{1}^{0.8}\frac{1}{0.3-x^4}dx
\end{equation}

I know that the number of Gauss points required for a polynomial of degree $p$ is given by
$p = 2n-1$, where $n$ is the number of points required. But since this function is not a polynomial, how can I determine the number of points required for getting the exact value of the integral?

Comment: No way. The exact value depends on logarithms, i.e. is (likely) a transcendental number. And all the values given by the quadrature are algebraic numbers.

Comment: @metamorphy so we just keep on increasing the number of gauss points until we reach the desired accuracy?

Comment: Yes (or split the original interval into smaller ones, and use the same number of points on each of these - if increasing the number of Gauss points gets too costy).

Comment: Be also aware of [some modern methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh-sinh_quadrature).

Comment: Is the lower bound correct or should that be $0.1$? Or why do you have the limits in the wrong order? The singularity of the integrand is at $x=0.74008..$ // Do you want to cover the full integration interval with one segment or are composite methods allowed? What is the requested accuracy for this numerical integration?

Comment: @LutzLehmann It's the way it is in the book. The accuracy desired is not mentioned. The author straight away uses 5 point gauss quadrature rule and states that the error is very small without any explanation why the 5 point formula was used. And I was curious whether only one segment method can achieve an exact solution without any error as in the case of polynomial functions.

Comment: Then depending on the origin date of the book, the implied accuracy might be the maximum possible for single or double precision, 7 or 15 decimal digits. This would be one way that one could get no better result using the selected tools.

Comment: Using the Gaussian quadrature from python's scipy.integrate.fixed_quad gives a result that is only accurate in the first 4 decimal digits, which somehow invalidates my last point.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: I must confess I didn't even notice the singularity. My bad 8-{|} Then the _supposed_ way of working around this issue is the principal concern.